# integrate RocketChat with website

Tags: javascript, java, rocket.chat

I want to use livechat feature from rocket.chat app .

if a user login to website before open the livechat popup , it should be authorized and be able to start chat, otherwise it should see a login form and then start to chat.
I use this code in my webpage for livechat popup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function (w, d, s, u) {
    debugger;
    w.RocketChat = function (c) {
        w.RocketChat._.push(c)
    };
    w.RocketChat._ = [];
    w.RocketChat.url = u;
    var h = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j = d.createElement(s);
    j.async = true;
    j.src = 'http://localhost/packages/rocketchat_livechat/assets/rocket-livechat.js';
    h.parentNode.insertBefore(j, h);
})(window, document, 'script', 'http://localhost/livechat');
```

thanks for time

Comment: check for session if exists show chat section

Comment: @BackSlash I want sent userId to server (if user logged in to site ,before).and show different form .it makes no sence that a logged in user , login again , just for chat .

Comment: @owaishanif786 how can do this in frontend , by javascript. how can alarm server to show different ui to user

Comment: @sahar You didn't answer my question. What have you tried? SO works like that: You try something, get stuck and come here with a specific question, including the code you tried and why it isn't working. If you didn't even try, you should.

Comment: @BackSlash aha. I just use a brief rocket.chat livechat script in my page . and then search and search to find answer of my question .but I didnt gain anything by now.I update my question

Answer (score 0):

The script has changed. You should now use the newer version.

Once you have enabled LiveChat on your Administration -> LiveChat, a new option will appear below you users menu called `LiveChat`. It is now lying between "My account" and "Administration".

Click on it. Then you will find "Instalation". Click on it and copy this new code on your website and you will be ready to go.